# SQL Server TCP Provider a connection cannot be established

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2012, laravel-blade

I'm trying to connect to a data base in SQL Server which is in a local server but on other PC, the error is:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP
> Provider: A connection cannot be established because the destination
> computer expressly denied the connection"

[image: ERROR]

I configured ODBC for the database, I tested the connection and it says "Tests completed successfully".

Here is an image, but it is in Spanish:

[image: ODCB]

Maybe it's the firewall? BTW I'm using php with Laravel 10

Comment: It could be the firewall on either machine (or both), yes. Also SQL Server needs to be explicitly [configured to allow remote connections](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+allow+remote+connections).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also content on [so] needs to be in English, that includes error messages.

Comment: Did you notice in the Test Connection screen shot that it's using "ODBC Driver 10 for SQL Server"? That's quite an old version of the driver, probably suitable for connecting to server versions up to SQL Server 2008, or 2008 R2. What version of SQL Server are you using? If you execute `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS, what's the output?